# \maketitle control sequence error

Tags: titles

I'm preparing a SIGCHI publication and trying to use their document class file (posted [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2ea5f4e1eb0fa6038b564c177094018a)), but whenever I try to compile my document I get the following error:

```
./test.tex:18: Undefined control sequence. 
<argument> ... single spaced. \newline \textcolor 
{red}{Every submission wil...
l.18 \maketitle
```

I've provided a dummy document below. I've put `\maketitle` in the proper location and included all the necessary arguments (title and author), so I'm not sure what's going on.

```
\documentclass{sigchi}
\usepackage{times}
\pagenumbering{arabic}  % Arabic page numbers for submission.  Remove this line to eliminate page numbers for the camera ready copy
\title{The Title}
\numberofauthors{2}
\author{
   \alignauthor Author 1
     \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
     \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \email{author@a.com}
   \alignauthor Author 2
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \email{author2@b.com}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\abstract{This is the abstract}
\keywords{Put author keywords here}
\classification{The ACM Classification keywords here.}

\section{Introduction}
blah
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\textcolor` is defined by the `color` package, if the class hasn't loaded it you could add `\usepackage{color}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David pointed out, the style file requires the `color` package. Once I added `\usepackage{color}` to the preamble, `\maketitle` worked fine.